# Consider the following statements concerning the graph of $x+2y-6=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have gone through few steps, but I don't know how to solve this problem.
Consider the following statements concerning the graph of $x+2y-6=0$.

A. The $y$-intercept is $6$

B. The $x$-intercept is $-6$

C. Slope is $1/2$

D. The domain and range are all real numbers.

So..I got to this stage so far.

$x+2y-6=0$

$x+2y=6$

$2y=6-x$

$y=2-x/2$

I have no clue what to do from here. I don't want just the answer. Can someone help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: do you understand what is meant by $x$-intercept and $y$-intercepts of a line?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Nevermind my steps. I have to choose 1 or more answers from A to D from the question "Consider the following statements concerning the graph of x+2y−6=0." I know that X is vertical and y is horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider that $y=3-\frac{1}{2}x$.

Simply plugging in numbers will eliminate options A, B, C. To see why D is true, simply look at the equation of the line for $y=3-\frac{1}{2}x$. It extends infinitely far vertically and horizontally; that is, its domain and range are all of the real numbers.

Comment: How did you get y=3−12x?

Comment: Divide $2y = 6 - x$ by $2$ on both sides.  You get $y = 3 - \frac12x$

Comment: But just by looking at  y=3−12x, how do I know what x and y are? I'm new to this category.

Comment: According to induktio, I'm supposed to plug in numbers as the question tells me, right? Look, (6)=3-1/2(-6) = 6=3-(-3) = 6=3+3 = 6. And the slope IS 1/2. Why should AB and C be eliminated?

Comment: Slope is negative.

Comment: So it would be A,B and D?